# How prove this $|1+x|^a\ge 1+ax+\dfrac{1}{1000}|x|^a$

Tags: inequality

> let  $2\le a\le 13,a\in R$,and $x\in R$,show that:
>   $$|1+x|^a\ge 1+ax+\dfrac{1}{1000}|x|^a\tag{1}$$

My try: let
$$f(x)=|1+x|^a-1-ax-\dfrac{1}{1000}|x|^a$$

and since if $x>-1$,then  $$|1+x|^a=(1+x)^a=1+ax+\dfrac{a(a-1)}{2}x^2+\cdots+x^a$$
and I fell this is nice reslut.because it is well konw this follow **Bernoulli inequality**

$$(1+x)^a\ge 1+ax,x>-1,a>1$$
But my inequality is strong than this .and  I use computer test found this inequality $(1)$ is true.and I can't 
 prove it.

**BY the way** I found in china  book have this

[image]
Thank you for you help

Comment: What is the problem about the proof in your book ?

Comment: in china book,http://item.jd.com/10192786.html, and you can download at  http://ishare.iask.sina.com.cn/f/23089172.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is a partial answer : I show below that inequality (1) holds
when $x\geq 0$ or $x \leq c_1=-\frac{1}{1-\big(\frac{1}{1000}\big)^{\frac{1}{13}}}$
(note that $c_1 \approx -2.42 \ldots$).

Let $g(x)=(1+x)^a-1-ax-x^a$ for $x\geq 0$. Then $g'(x)=a(1+x)^{a-1}-a-ax^{a-1}$,
$g''(x)=a(a-1)\big((1+x)^{a-2}-x^{a-2}\big)$, so $g'$ is increasing, and hence 
$g'(x) \geq g'(0)=a(a-1) >0$, so $g$ is increasing, and hence 
$g(x) \geq g(0)=0$. So when $x\geq 0$ we have
$|1+x|^a \geq 1+ax+|x|^a$, which is stronger than (1).

Next, if $x\leq c_1$ then $|x| \geq |c_1|$, 
$1-\frac{1}{|x|}\geq 1-\frac{1}{|c_1|}=\big(\frac{1}{1000}\big)^{\frac{1}{13}}$,
so $\bigg(1-\frac{1}{|x|}\bigg)^a \geq \frac{1}{1000}$. It follows that
$|1+x|^a \geq \frac{1}{1000}|x|^a$, which is also stronger than (1).

Answer (score -1):

The value of the function in 0 is 0 for every a. The function is continuous, so you could do the derivative and use binomial theorem to prove that for every x > 0 is positive and for every x < 0 is negative.

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFhhD.jpg